# Compiled libcurl and OpenSSL separately, is it the same as compiling libcurl with OpenSSL?

Tags: c++, openssl, libcurl

So, I have compiled the following:

**libcurl:** x86/debug, x86/release, x64/debug, x64/release

**OpenSSL:** x86/debug, x86/release, x64/debug, x64/release

Now, I have setup visual studio for all those configs with both libcurl and OpenSSL included.

I have seen people mention compiling libcurl with OpenSSL. Is it the same as what I did?

BTW, if I run this:

```
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    curl_version_info_data* vinfo = curl_version_info(CURLVERSION_NOW);
    if (vinfo->features & CURL_VERSION_SSL)
        std::cout << "yes" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "no" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
yes
```

Does this mean my setup is good, if I want to use libcurl with SSL support?

Also, if order matters, I compiled libcurl first and then OpenSSL.

Platform: Windows

Toolchain: VC++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need OpenSSL at all when building `libcurl` on Windows.

`libcurl` by default uses Schannel ([WinCNG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/cng-portal), Windows native crypto) when built on Windows.

If `CURL_VERSION_SSL` is reporting `true` then SSL support is enabled correctly.

Comment: Does that mean I don't have to mess with CA bundles and **pems**? And will setting **CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER** suffice?

Comment: Schannel uses the Windows integrated trust store. So if the site is using a CA-signed cert then it will just work indeed.